# symfony nested query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

how can I execute a nested query with symfony & doctrine queryBuilder?
for example:

```
select data.name from
(
  select case when name = 'Alfred' then 'Thomas' else name end as name
  from employee
) as data;
```

Thanks

Comment: This subqury is an example right

Comment: Yes it'an example

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using native sql:

```
    $stmt = $this->doctrine->getConnection()->prepare('your_query');
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
```